# Load Multiple js file after page load

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-core

I have multiple JavaScript files which are loaded before page load which are affecting page speed. I want that my JS files to load after page load though to improve page speed.

I tried to use `async` and `defer` but due to dependency to each other, this way is not working out for me. I also tried lazy loading through AJAX but that is also not working for me (using this link https://w3bits.com/async-javascript)

```
@section Scripts {
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=API_KEY&sensor=false&libraries=places"></script>
  <script src="/lib/bootstrap-datetimepicker/js/moment.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script src="/lib/bootstrap-datetimepicker/js/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script> 
  <script src="/js/viewcomponent/windowsignup.js"></script>
  <script type='text/javascript' src='/js/viewcomponent/kundliregistrationwindow.js' async='async'></script>
}
```

I use multiple JS files on a page and I want them all to load after page load. Is there any way to do that?

Comment: Have you thought of bundling and minify the JS files https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/client-side/bundling-and-minification

Comment: js file which are common for all i already bundled but these are not common for all pages

Comment: Where are you having your script tags? In the html header or in the body? If you put it into the header, the browser should usually do load them in the background (and multiple files at once, but there's a limit per domain). Also make sure to use CDN versions of your libraries, not serve them yourself. CND versions are often cached from the users former visit on another page which required the exact same version of your library and the browser won't have to download it in this case

Comment: Can you show your `_Layout.cshtml`, where you render the `Scripts` section?

Answer (score 1):

You usually use a `Scripts` section to control the location where your scripts are being rendered in the document. The way browsers work, they will interpret the HTML from top to bottom. If they encounter a `<script>` tag, they will pause the HTML rendering and interpret the JavaScript first. For external JavaScript files this means that they will be included and interpreted first (if they aren’t marked as `defer` or `async`).

As such, a common practice is to add JavaScript at the end of the `<body>` tag. That way, the scripts will not prevent rendering the document first but they will also execute early enough to be able to immediately have an effect. In addition, since they are executed after the majority of the `<body>` has already been interpreted, they can directly access DOM elements. So you generally don’t need to listen to another DOM event first before you can do something with the DOM.

For example, this would work just fine:

```
<body>
    <div id="foo"></div>
    <script>
        var foo = document.getElementById('foo');
    </script>
</body>
```

However, if you had the `<script>` before the `<div>` (or inside of the `<head>`), the script would fail to find the `foo` element simply because it isn’t added to the DOM yet.

For ASP.NET Core this means that you should make sure that your `Scripts` section is added at the end of your `<body>` tag inside your layouts file. So it should look like this:

```
 <!-- (The rest of the layout) -->

 @RenderSection("Scripts", required: false)

 </body>
 </html>
```

You can also add script tags *before* the `RenderSection` call to make sure that those scripts are available on all pages but loaded before other scripts. For example, if you are using Bootstrap and you want to use jQuery, it might make sense to include that globally for all pages. But since you have it before the other scripts, it is available for the other scripts.

As far as dependencies between scripts go, make sure that you include the scripts in the order they need to executed. So if you have script B that depends on functions in script A, make sure to include A before B. But then, without using `defer` or `async`, just including them should work just fine.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `getScript` inside `document.ready`.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $.getScript("domainpath/lib/bootstrap-datetimepicker/js/moment.js");
});
```

It's fetch your `js` after `dom` ready.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Jquery](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.getscript/)'s `$.getScript()` function but then you have to keep an eye on proper loading order. Would recommend more to bundle all necessary files on the server side and only serve a single file

Answer (score 0):

When the browser receives a request for an HTML file the DOM starts to draw. If you place your scripts in the `<head>` tag the DOM stops from rendering and the browser starts to execute the `<script> files`.
One solution could be to place your `<script>` files at the end of the `<body>`.
Another solution could be to dynamically load your scripts into your page after the page is loaded like this:

```js
window.addEventListener('load', () => {
  let script = document.createElement('script');
  script.src = './my_lazy_loaded_script.js';
  document.body.appendChild(script);
});
```

If you have multiple files that are dependent on each other you could do something like this using the `async/await mechanism`:

```js
window.addEventListener('load', async () => {
    console.log('page loaded')
    try{
        await loadFileAsync('./my_first_lazy_load.js');
        await loadFileAsync('./my_second_lazy_load.js'); 
    } catch(err){
        console.log(err);
    } finally {
        console.log('Everything loaded')
    }
})

const loadFileAsync = (url) => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        if(url){
            let script = document.createElement('script');
            script.src = url;
            document.body.appendChild(script);
            resolve(true);
        } else {
            reject(false);
        }
    });
}
```

If you want to load your scripts as soon as the `DOM` is rendered, you can replace `window.addEventListener('load',()=>{})` with `document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {})`

Comment: While this will generally help to avoid dependency issues, adding scripts _after_ the document’s `load` event will generally only decrease the page speed as the document needs to finish rendering _completely_ before the scripts are added and executed.

Comment: Thank you for the comment but, I am not sure if I understood correctly what you are saying. This is exactly what `window.addEventListener('load')` or `document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded')` does (waits for the page to be completely loaded or for the `DOM` to be rendered). With this approach it doesn't matter where the `@Script` section is placed and of course the solution can be improved.

Comment: Yes, that’s my point, you are always waiting for the document to be loaded. But the event happens pretty late and as such you are just delaying script execution usually longer than it needs to be. If you want scripts to run quickly (ideally without the user noticing), you shouldn’t wait for DOM events.

Comment: I understand now what you are saying. If you are manipulating the DOM in the used scripts, this is a safe solution. If you are not using DOM operations you can use the async/await approach in the head dirrectly or at the end of the body.